# Any known limits to calls per minute for webapps?

Tags: google-apps-script, concurrency, limits

Im getting inconsistent behaviours when sending POST requests to a google apps script deployed as webapp.

I have a desktop app sending POST calls to a GAS webapp. This calls may be totally variable in their cadence, from 1 in several minutes, to bursts of dozens per second.

In my tests I have found requests seemingly lost, requests that don't progress along the webapp internal logic flow (like script instances that get cut or interrupeted (?)), while others work flawlessly. There is no evident pattern.

However, trying things around, I found that if I space the calls, adding a pause between requests, everything normalizes.

Are there stablished and known limits for this? The only option I have to solve this is to introduce this artificial intervals between calls? I have not found information on this in the GAS [quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

Any help and ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Update: The issue seems to be related with overlaping access to storage services.

Webapp requests even distanced half second between them, introduce a seemingly false redundandy on the service, where requests accessing Script Properties or Cache Service will produce issues.

In my latest (and simplest) test, just sent 6 requests in 3 seconds, trying to do a simple counter increment per request (in the script properties) produced variable incorrect outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirming in the answer: there is no evident or documented per-minute limit on the number of requests to a GAS webapp.

The issue I'm experimenting is related to concurrency. Even when they are coming from the same source, fast paced requests can produce concurrency issues when accesing storage services like Cache or Properties.

This should be handled using the Lock Service.

Comment: I'm assuming that you tried to deal with this issue using `Lock Service`  My experience is, that Lock Service is basically useless.  Even if it does prevent sections of code from running concurrently, it doesn't seem to "stack" the instances and run them when the previous code is done.  How it works internally, I have no idea, but I've also been doing some tests and looking into this issue, and have come to the conclusion that there is no "built-in" way to handle concurrency.  Lock Service is misleading.  "On Form Submit" code seems to handle writing concurrent data to the **Form** no problem.

Comment: But anything other than the On Form Submit trigger, doesn't seem to have any way of handling rapid bursts of reading and writing data without something getting messed up.  The JavaScript itself seems to handle concurrency with no problem.  The issue is when multiple instances of code are trying to read/write to the same source.

Comment: Indeed, I had mixed experiences using Lock Service. I have found that it works, as long as the locked part of code do not call other portions of code (functions) of the script. But even that I could not affirm without some doubt as I had to go through a lot of changes and tries until getting something working. It does work for me though, it seems to stack things well, but Im not using Forms, but a script deployed as webapp.

Comment: Glad to know that Lock Service is actually working for you as long as you don't call other functions.  That's good to know.  I guess I never figured that out, as my code branches to lots of other places.